# Excel pivot table: Columns at the same level hierarchy

Tags: excel, pivot

This is the table I want to arrange as a pivot table:
[https://imgur.com/a/ck9rFXM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhT6D.png)

I would like that the columns "Size" and "Country of origin" appear in the pivot at the same level hierarchy, so that the values "Big", "Medium" and "Small" appear in the first three columns (as well as the Grand Total at the end), following all countries of origin in the next columns (and the Grand Total at the end).

Here is what I tried, but countries are at a lower level inside the "Size" field:
[https://imgur.com/a/blZYf0w](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUjrN.png)

Comment: You can create two pivots (First for size and second for country) side by side?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the possibility of doing it in a single step.